# Como mudar o nível de logging de uma dependência?

Tags: java, maven, junit, logging

Estou tentando lidar com o nível de logging de uma dependência, onde ela esta mostrando **INFO** e eu não gostaria que ela mostrasse esse nível, pois a informação não é pertinente, no meu caso é o nível de logging do JUnit 5.

Segue o resultado do logging da dependência quando rodo meu código:

```
Sep 19, 2019 12:17:47 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters fromClasspathResource
INFO: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource [file:/E:/root/scalableapitesting/target/classes/junit-platform.properties].

Sum result is : 10
Subtraction result is : 5

Sep 19, 2019 12:17:47 AM org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.EnumConfigurationParameterConverter get
INFO: Using parallel execution mode 'SAME_THREAD' set via the 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default' configuration parameter.
Sep 19, 2019 12:17:47 AM org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.EnumConfigurationParameterConverter get
INFO: Using parallel execution mode 'CONCURRENT' set via the 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default' configuration parameter.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Toda parte do INFO, eu gostaria de remover.

Pelo pesquisei, a api de logging que o JUnit 5 usa:

*JUnit uses the **Java Logging APIs** in the java.util.logging package (a.k.a. JUL) to emit warnings and debug information. Please refer to the official documentation of LogManager for configuration options.*

Vi coisas sobre o `logging.properties`, `log4j.properties` porém ainda não consegui mudar o nível, acredito que algum arquivo de configuração será possível modificar isso.

Dependência no `pom.xml` que esta gerando o logging:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Você pode regular o nível de log por pacotes, por exemplo, configurar o nível para o pacote `org.junit.platform` como `INFO`. Poste seu `log4j.properties` ou `logging.properties` ou `slf4j` ...

Comment: Bom, depois de mais investigacoes, descobri que, quando usando o JUL, se voce quiser apontar pra um logging.properties diferente, alem de criar o arquivo voce deve apontar pelo java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, a solução final foi "apontar" onde esta o arquivo que tem as propriedades que eu quero no java, nesse caso ele ta na pasta resources.

Isso é:

```java
//Solução
String loggingPath = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logging.properties").getFile();
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", loggingPath);
```

Na documentação do JUL, o standard é procurar a nível de JRE (o que eu achei um tanto quanto estranho) pois alterar para a aplicação X pode causar efeito na aplicação Y.

Sobre alterar propriedades do sistema, como estou rodando cada jar em contêineres isolados não sera um problema alterar a propriedade do sistema.

No meu arquivo de configuração (que já existia), a linha que faz oque eu quero é essa:

```java
org.junit.level=WARNING
```